# AngularJS: url parameters for routing

Tags: parameters, routes, angularjs, view

I would like to use **url parameters for routing** in angularjs

I have an anguar app with 2 views : 
editView and mainView

Given a url that looks like this:
'httx://myapp/?param1=x&...**&editmode=1**&...'

-> will get me to the /editMode Path

*What would be a good way to do so?*

- would i need to use a controller to get the $routeparams.editmode and use the $location.path('/editmode') if editmode == 1 ?
- do i need html5 mode?
- There is nothing i can do about the url - i am forced to use the editmode parameter

---

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
  controller: function($routeParams, $location) {
    if($routeParams.editmode == '1') {
      $location.path('editMode') ...
```

Comment: Looks like you have server providing search params. Angular Routes parse the url hash, not search. Why do you need both methods?

Comment: I work with SharePoint 2013 apps and my angular app gets called like this: src="~appWebUrl/Pages/DemoPage.aspx?{StandardTokens}&wpId=_WPID_&editmode=_editMode_&wpq=_WPQ_&weblocaleId=_WebLocaleId_"   where appWebUrl is a link to the "app-Web" and {standartTokens} resolves to a bunch of parameters

Comment: ok...so your asp outputs dynamic js based on url params? Should be able to just add `$scope.editMode= <%aspcode%>`...couldn't you?

Comment: in my controller i can add: if($routeParams.editMode == '1') { $location.path(editMode)} ... but is this the way to go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that "resolve:" instead of "controller:" was what i needed.
If anyone is interested in changing routes via params, this is the way to go:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1838#issuecomment-13994168